Fourier transform and Convolution theorem in 2D
I want to simplify $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(B \cdot C) \cdot A)$ such that $C$ can brought out of equation as much as possible. Using $\mathcal{F}(u * v) = \mathcal{F}(u) \cdot \mathcal{F}(v)$ and $\mathcal{F}(u \cdot v) = \mathcal{F}(u) * \mathcal{F}(v)$, I was able to derive the following.
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(B \cdot C) \cdot A) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}([\mathcal{F}(B) * \mathcal{F}(C)] \cdot A) \\ = \mathcal{F}^{-1}([A \cdot \mathcal{F}(B) * \mathcal{F}(C)]) \\ = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(A \cdot \mathcal{F}(B)) \cdot C $$
Which is sufficiently simplified for my use case.
However, when I try to implement the expression in Python I do not obtain the same field ($\phi = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(B \cdot C) \cdot A)$ should be equivalent to $\phi_2 = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(A \cdot \mathcal{F}(B)) \cdot C$).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.fft import fft2, ifft2

def Af(x, y):
    return np.exp(-2*(x**2 + y**2))

def Bf(x, y):
    return np.sin(x*y)

def Cf(x, y):
    return np.sin(0.2*x*y)

# Grid
N = 128
x = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, N)
y = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, N)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Sample functions and pad
A = np.pad(Af(X, Y), pad_width=N)
B = np.pad(Bf(X, Y), pad_width=N)
C = np.pad(Cf(X, Y), pad_width=N)

# Should be equivalent?
phi = ifft2(fft2(B * C) * A)
phi2 = ifft2(A * fft2(B)) * C

plt.imshow(np.abs(phi)**2)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
plt.imshow(np.abs(phi2)**2)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

Below are the images I obtain, which are clearly different.
$\phi$" />
$\phi_2$" />
What am I doing wrong?

You're probably off by DFT/IDFT scaling factors.  Try passing in norm='ortho' for all of your FFTs and IFFTs to use a unitary version of the transform.
